# TypeInformation is missing from the classpath when i build flink1.6.1 in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-flink

Error:(58, 7) Symbol 'type .typeinfo.TypeInformation' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'macro method org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.createTypeInformation'.
Make sure that type TypeInformation is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of .typeinfo.
      tableEnv.fromDataStream(dataStream, fields:_*)

Comment: Could you improve your question a bit? What exactly are you trying to build? Is it the flink source code itself? Which version? Have you tried doing what the message says: full rebuild? Also you may try reimporting the project to IDEA.

Comment: I build full project of  flink 1.6.1 in IDEA  and it come up to this error

Comment: it work by  building   flink 1.5   in IDEA

Comment: having you meet   this error  when  building   flink1.6.1  by idea